How to set Ubuntu Loaded USB as boot option through BIOS
My pc is black screen after the loading screen. I'm trying to set the usb with Ubuntu as the first boot option so i can get into the computer. I've tried going to boot options -> add boot option -> ubuntu-serv,[VenHw()/memoryMapped/USB] -> then I got to the EFI folder and selected all the files from there, but still the pc wont boot properly it goes black and then back to the BIOS.

I'm using NVIDIA Jetson BIOS
